# Keras functional api multiple input: The list of inputs passed to the model is redundant

Tags: python, keras

I have a huge networt ([keras-bert](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-bert)) which works fine for classification. Since my data has two different columns, I'd like to fine-tune a BERT model for each column and connect them in the final layer. But I get the following error:

> ---> 20 model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs(self)
>
> 1620     """Validates the inputs and outputs of a Graph Network."""
>
> 1621     # Check for redundancy in inputs.
>
> -> 1622     if len(set(self.inputs)) != len(self.inputs):
>
> 1623       raise ValueError('The list of inputs passed to the model '
>
> 1624                        'is redundant. '
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

In my code I have two bert models, `model1`and `model2`. With just one model it worked fine. The only things I added were that 2 models instead of one are loaded from checkpoint and the second input-layer and the concatenation of dense1 and dense2:

```
#load_trained_model_from_checkpoint is defined here:
# https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-bert/blob/master/keras_bert/loader.py
model1 = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(
    config_path,
    checkpoint_path,
    training=True,
    trainable=True,
    seq_len=SEQ_LEN,
    )
model2 = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(
    config_path,
    checkpoint_path,
    training=True,
    trainable=True,
    seq_len=SEQ_LEN,
)

inputs1 = model1.inputs[:2] #model 1 for titles
inputs2 = model2.inputs[:2] #model 2 for texts
dense1 = model1.get_layer('NSP-Dense').output
dense2 = model2.get_layer('NSP-Dense').output
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(len(test_title_y[0]), activation='sigmoid')(keras.layers.concatenate([dense1, dense2]))


model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
```

What am I overseeing? Do I somehow have to wrap the input?

**Edit:**
I suspect that the problem has something to do with my input being a list of lists: the inputs1 and inputs2 look like that:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'Input-Token:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Input-Segment:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>]
[<tf.Tensor 'Input-Token_1:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Input-Segment_1:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>]
```

Can I somehow reshape or concatenate my input to overcome this error?

**Edit:**

The summaries of model1 looks like that, model2 looks the same but with LAYER_2 for each layer name:

> Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
>
> ---
>
> Input-Token (InputLayer)        (None, 256)          0
>
> ---
>
> Input-Segment (InputLayer)      (None, 256)          0
>
> ---
>
> Embedding-Token (TokenEmbedding [(None, 256, 768), ( 23440896    Input-Token[0][0]
>
> ---
>
> Embedding-Segment (Embedding)   (None, 256, 768)     1536        Input-Segment[0][0]
>
> ---
>
> ... (lots of layers in between)
>
> ---
>
> NSP-Dense (Dense)               (None, 768)          590592      Extract[0][0]

Comment: Are `model1` and `model2` created from the same original model? Do they use the same `original_model.input`?

Comment: I edited my post accordingly, both models are build from config and loaded with pretrained weights from a checkpoint.

Comment: Can you show the summary of model1 and model2? They seem to be identical (same config path, same tensors)

Comment: @DanielMöller I added a part of the model summary to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may sound a little copy+paste, but I think you solved your own question when you noticed the inputs are lists of lists.

Instead of using `[inputs1, inputs2]`, use `inputs1 + inputs2`.

Test if they are lists with `isinstance(inputs1, list)`.

Comment: yes, they are both lists, I am still not sure how to resolve the problem though.

Comment: Join the lists with `+` just like in the answer.

Comment: WHat if they are not lists?

Comment: @DanielMöller I got the same error, but my inputs are not list, they are tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor, any clues as to resolve this error?

Comment: @the_learning_child, it's not possible to know your problem, it it's saying it's a list, then it's a list. You must find where.

Comment: @DanielMöller Sorry, I got it fixed. I actually messed the order in which i was giving the input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an internal check which looks for equal length inputs to a model. In this case both inputs are `[batchSize, 256]`. One thing that you can do is try packing the two inputs into one with three dimensions (i.e. `[batchSize, inputs, 256]`). You would need to handle some slicing in the model to make sure you are passing the correct input to the layers.

Here is an example:

```
#load_trained_model_from_checkpoint is defined here:
# https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-bert/blob/master/keras_bert/loader.py

model1 = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(
    config_path,
    checkpoint_path,
    training=True,
    trainable=True,
    seq_len=SEQ_LEN,
    )
model2 = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(
    config_path,
    checkpoint_path,
    training=True,
    trainable=True,
    seq_len=SEQ_LEN,
)

inputs1 = model1.inputs[:2] #model 1 for titles
inputs2 = model2.inputs[:2] #model 2 for texts
# concatenate the inputs into one tensor
concatInputs = keras.backend.concatenate([inputs1, inputs2],axis=0)

dense1 = model1.get_layer('NSP-Dense').output
dense2 = model2.get_layer('NSP-Dense').output

def getModel():
    inputs=keras.layers.Input([2,256])
    # slice inputs into individual tensors
    in1 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.slice(inputs,[0,0],[1,inputs.get_shape()[1]])
    in2 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.slice(inputs,[1,0],[2,inputs.get_shape()[1]])
    d1 = dense1(in1)
    d2 = dense2(in2)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(len(test_title_y[0]), activation='sigmoid')(keras.layers.concatenate([d1, d2]))

    return inputs,outputs

ins,outs = getModel()

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[ins], outputs=[outs])
```

I didn't get a chance to test so the syntax may not be exact but the idea should work.

Answer (score -1):

The error means that somewhere, the function is trying to use a list as a hash argument instead. i.e. using a list as a key in a dictionary.

The Model(inputs=[input1,input2]) cannot take in a list.

Try using

```
np.reshape
```

On input1 and input2 first. Additionally, cast the lists to tuples.